# Critical CSS for multiple pages and breakpoints

Tags: css, performance, web

I have a CSS file that I need to optimize for loading. It's big with many different components that are used on many different pages (start page, category pages, detail pages) on different breakpoints (mobile, table, desktop), thus manual optimization is complicated. At least extracting the most important parts would help load times (as it's blocking rendering) - the current big file can be loaded async.

What I've tried is using the various critical css extractors and uncss. But all of them can only extract the CSS for one page in one breakpoint.

Is there any tool that I've missed? I'm looking for something that can do

`magic-used-css-extractor 400px,1024px,2048px http://example.com/ http://example.com/category1/ http://example.com/category2/ http://example.com/detail1/ http://example.com/detail2/`

and returns a CSS that matches the used CSS on all of these pages. Or a tool that can merge a couple of critical CSS in correct order with at-rules.

Comment: Have you tried this using the Grunt UnCSS package? https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss You can point it to each page, provide different breakpoints and it will spit out css for each page. You might need to use a different critical CSS file for each page....

Comment: Yes I've tried uncss. I've gave it a couple of URLs and I've got a CSS that consists of the 'uncssed' CSS rules of all of these URLs concatenated. So if you give it 20 URLs you get the CSS of the common header 20 times. It would only work if there is a CSS merger, but I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just yesterday I've seen a trick done by https://github.com/addyosmani/critical

It supports multiple dimensions, but not multiple pages. Still the same trick might be applied to merge the critical css after running it on a couple of important pages.

The tool critical is using is https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css, which would remove duplicate rules and therefor merge multiple css files.

See here for reference: https://github.com/addyosmani/critical/blob/master/lib/core.js#L30